# Count based on inner select

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to do a count based on a sub select statement.

```
SELECT MONTH(Received), State, COUNT('id'), SUM(price) FROM Leads GROUP BY MONTH(Received), State
```

That query works and generates something like this

```
MONTH(Received)     State   COUNT('id')    SUM(price)
4                   CA      25             35
4                   UT      13             8
```

What I'm trying to count is how many rows had a price > 0

This is the query I tried

```
SELECT MONTH(Received), SUM(price), COUNT(`id`), (SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM Leads WHERE Price > 0) as NumPaidLeads, State FROM Leads GROUP BY MONTH(Received), State
```

But `NumPaidLeads` Counts the entire column, the price column is numeric type.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that `COUNT('id')` counts the *string* `id` while `COUNT(\`id\`)` counts the *column* `id`.

Comment: Please add some sample data of your table.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case for count the rows  with price > 0 you could use a case

```
SELECT MONTH(Received), State, 
 sum( case when price > 0 then 1 else 0 END) num_row_with_price, SUM(price) 
FROM Leads 
GROUP BY MONTH(Received), State
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include *state* in the where-clause of your sub-select.
The case-solution in the other post may be faster, though.

```
SELECT MONTH(Received), SUM(price), COUNT(`id`), 
 (SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM Leads as L1 WHERE Price > 0 
  and L1.State=L2.State) as NumPaidLeads,
 State FROM Leads as L2 GROUP BY MONTH(Received), State
```